# returning values via return or out with structs efficiency

Tags: c#

say you had a function like this, where vector3 is a struct

```
  public static Vector3 VectorOperation(ref Vector3 a, ref Vector3 b)
```

would this be more efficient, or

```
  public static void VectorOperation(ref Vector3 a, ref Vector3 b, out Vector3 c)
```

I know with the second one, there are no unnecessary copies of the struct. The values written to c are written directly to the caller's variable.

However with the first one, I'm uncertain if it goes directly into the caller's variable like the second one or if there are unnecessary copies of the struct that can lead to inefficiencies.

Comment: Did you see problems with your code or are you trying to solve problem that doesn't even exist yet? I would say - go with the more readable solution and fix the problems as they appear. I wouldn't expect the return value to have much of perf impact unless you call it billions of times.

Comment: Interesting question, but seriously, this has to be a micro-optimization at best.

Comment: This would result in equivalent performance.

Comment: @Hristo Can you explain why?